# Error 3 while encrypting in CBC mode Python AES Error

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I am using `pycryptodome` to encrypt and decrypt a message. Below is the code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

obj = AES.new('secret key 12345'.encode("utf-8"), AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456'.encode("utf-8"))
message = "The answer is no".encode("utf-8")
encryptedmsg = obj.encrypt(message)


obj2 = AES.new('secret key 12345'.encode("utf-8"), AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456'.encode("utf-8"))
t = obj2.decrypt(encryptedmsg)
print(t)
```

Now above code is perfectly working fine. What I have noticed here is that if you encrypt a message which  has length greater or smaller than the key, then it gives error `Error 3 while encrypting in CBC mode`. For ex, in this case, secret key is `secret key 12345` which has length of 16. Now if we create any message with 16 length then it works fine but if message length is 15 or 17 then it gives this error.

Why is this behavior and how can solve this issue.

Comment: You should use [`pad()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#Crypto.Util.Padding.pad) and [`unpad()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#Crypto.Util.Padding.unpad) from [`Crypto.Util.Padding`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-padding-module).

Comment: For AES with CBC, the length of the plaintext must be an integer multiple of the block size (16 bytes). This applies regardless of the key, which for AES may be 16, 24 or 32 bytes in size. If the length of the plaintext does not meet this condition, it must be padded to the required length, see the previous comment.

Comment: @Topaco Does this rule applies to all the modes present of AES or its just with CBC. Is there any mode where no pading is required

Comment: There are modes of operation that change a block cipher (like AES) into a stream cipher, e.g. CTR, see [block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation), so that no padding is required. Note that the individual modes generally have certain demands, e.g. on the IV, which must be considered when changing.

Comment: @Topaco using `CTR` mode, it decrypts in hex format. `b'G\xd2\x15Y\x82\xbb}s\xdeq\xbe\x19\r(\xdb|P'` How can I convert it back to readable format.?

Comment: Sorry, but it's impossible to analyze the issue with this information. Why don't you check the PyCryptodome documentation for an encryption/decryption example, e.g. [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#ctr-mode) or [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-counter-module), if a counter object should be used? Or of course, post your code so that an analysis is possible.